# People from the Nordics Living Abroad

Tags: data-request, migration

I am looking for data regarding Nordics (Denmark, Norway, Sweden, Finland) living abroad. I was wondering whether there were any up-to-date resources for the stocks of people from the Nordics already located in foreign nations. I have found the OECD and UN databases, but they are either not up to date or are lacking in data for certain countries (in particular Singapore seems to guard its demographics data very fiercely).

I would also be interested in whether there were already some analyses regarding the financial backgrounds of emigrants from the Nordics - i.e. profession, or income prior to migration - to see the economic make-up of Nordic emigrants. I have been through the official statistics bureaus for the Nordic nations already so I would be looking for independent research available online.

Comment: Hi, I'm curious. Why makes  you say that Singapore guard the data fiercely?